# How can excel take two seperate cells with comma seperated data and pair them up?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have looked all over for an answer to this and seem to be stuck fast.

I have something like this:

```
Cell B1:    01/01/2014,01/02/2014, 01/03/2014, 01/04/2014, 01/05/2014, 01/06/2014, 01/07/2014, 01/08/2014, 01/09/2014, 01/10/2014

Cell B2:    10.00,11.00,12.00,13.00,14.00,15.00,16.00,17.00,18.00,19.00
```

now I need something to take those values, and pair them up instantly like so.....

```
Cell B3: 01/01/2014 10.00, 01/02/2014 11.00, 01/03/2014 12.00...etc.
```

Now the dates in Cell B1 change depending on whats typed in as it is customer transaction dates, and B2 changes all the time as its those customers transaction amounts. Does anyone have an idea on how I can match them up like that in the simplest way possible?

Once I have it paired up like that (ie 01/01/2014 10.00, 01/02/2014 11.00 etc.) I then need the resulting cell to be easily pulled out of Excel and put into an email template (all of that is already designed and working, just need the functionality to do the pairing.

I thank anyone who has an idea how to do this!!!

Comment: Would a VBA solution suffice or are you trying to do this with native formulas?

Comment: preferably native but VBA can be used as the workbook already has plenty of vba macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not break up the data. Select column B and go to data tab - text to columns - delimited - comma

Now in B3 put `=Concatenate(B1," ",B2)` and drag it across.

Now they are paired. You want them back together, use `concatenate` again.

---

#### macro

```
Sub test()
Dim arrdate As Variant
Dim arrtime As Variant
Dim strcombo As String

arrdate = Split(Range("B1"), ",")
arrtime = Split(Range("B2"), ",")
strcombo = arrdate(0) & " " & arrtime(0) & ", "

For i = 1 To UBound(arrdate)
    strcombo = strcombo & arrdate(i) & " " & arrtime(i) & ", "
Next i
Range("b3") = strcombo
End Sub
```

Comment: aahh that would be because the users of this is not just me. they are all call center staff and have no idea how to do such things. need some function to do it automatically and output the answer like the example of B3 above.

Comment: @DarylBall if you want it done automatically, I'd say you need a macro, which will be a problem for them as well. Are the number of dates and times always the same?

Comment: not in this case, it depends how many transaction someone is raising as problems, so it changes each time it is used. Macro's and VBA are an option, as it already has a lot of macro's and VBA underneath, but as it SEEMS such a simple thing in my mind but i cannot find a way to do it.

Comment: @DarylBall posted a macro that will work. You could make it an activesheet.change if you wanted.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to set b3, you could just pass strcombo on to your emailing function as an argument.

Comment: you sir, are a hero!!!! Thank you soooo much!!!